# UIWebView: Link to files in bundle and set a baseURL

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, nsbundle

I am wanting to include a few .js files into the HTML file that I load into my `UIWebView`. These files are inside of my `app bundle`. I am also wanting to set a different `baseURL` for the `webView`.

So far, I am using the following:

HTML File:

```
... a bunch more html code above
<head>
<script src="%wJQ%" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head>
... a bunch more html code below
```

File that loads my `UIWebView`:

```
NSString *jQ = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"myjsfile" withExtension:@"js"] absoluteString];
htmlString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%wJQ%" withString:jQ];
```

This gives me something like:

```
<script src="file://localhost/Users/webmaster/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/5.1/Applications/43C9E1C2-C7FD-4FC1-BF6A-844266920CCD/MyApp.app/myjsfile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Sadly, when I view the `UIWebView` it doesn't seem to load the .js file.

Then, I am wanting to set my `baseURL` to a remote URL, because I need some relative links to work:

```
NSString *webURL = @"http://www.mysite.com";
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:webURL]];
```

How can I get both of these techniques working correctly together?

Comment: What is the content of the file you are loading?

Comment: If its just javascript (even though you call it htmlString) then you can't run it by loading it, you need to call stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString() to execute it. If its JS embedded in html then we'd need to see it to see why its not working.

Comment: It is just a javascript file. But I also have some css files in my bundle as well. But I need to be able to set the `baseURL` of my `UIWebView` to a domain, that is why I am trying to do it this way.

Comment: I am not trying to execute the javascript. I just want to link it inside of my .html file that my `UIWebView` is loading.

Answer (score 0):

If the javascript files can't be accessed because you have to set the base url to something else then maybe you could inject the javascript file(s) instead.

Where you inject the js will depend upon what it does and how it interacts with the dom. If its independent of the dom you could inject it on viewDidLoad, if its dependant you will need to inject it in shouldStartLoadWithRequest or webViewDidFinishLoad. 
Inject it like this:

```
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSURL *jsURL = [bundle URLForResource:@"JavaScript" withExtension:@"js"];  
    NSData *jsData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:jsURL];
    NSString *jsScriptAsString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:jsData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsScriptAsString];
```

Change your js file to this:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');  
script.type = 'text/javascript';  
script.text = your stuff
...
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Comment: Why can't I just set the path (inside the .html file) to my javascript files using the bundle URL?

Comment: Then why don't you try and see if that works. Then if it does will the bundle url be the same on every device?

Comment: Yeah, I did try and it didn't work. Guess I was just hoping someone had figured this out previously...